# PHP to force download breaks document

Tags: php, file

I am using the following code in a php document to force download of a pdf form since the submission works only after you have it on your local machine rather online.

It downloads the file ok but it corrupts it.
I can no longer open the pdf document.

```
<?php 
$file_name = 'costumer.pdf';
$file_url = 'http://www.lopezi.com/forms/' . $file_name;
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);

?>
```

Comment: It is Impossible that this code can modify the contents of your `PDF` file and `corrupt` it

Comment: Why are you doing a readfile() from a url? that forces your server to do a full-blown http request to fetch this file. Especially pointless if that's your own server to begin with... If the files are corrupted on download, then save the file, fetching a known good copy, and compare the too, see what's changed.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ unless the PHP file itself generates warnings or notices.

Comment: tip: when dealing with strange file formats (like pdf ;) ) in php, open the resulting file with a text editor - there may be notices or warnings inserted into the output, that the default viewing application can not handle

Comment: well the code does something @HankyPankyㇱ since the original file is just fine. read file @ Marc B with url, yes, newbie. @ cypherable, no warnings or errors opening with notepad

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header shouldn't be needed in this case. Further I suspect that you have corruption in the outputted file.

Download it somewhere, open notepad, and drag the file in there. If any PHP warnings or errors were generated you will see them at the top.

Also, try to avoid the option of having more content return from the script, causing problems with the download, end with something like:

```
die(file_get_contents($file_url));
```

This way you cannot accidentally break the code easily by adding more output.

Comment: thanks for the tips. i´ve opened with notepad: no errors. the original file is ok.